# Printing the Address of Elements in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java so i m trying this code but it's showing address of Elements in an array. How can i print the elements instead of printing the address of those elements in array?

```
for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        array[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<number2;i++){
        array2[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    if(array.length==0){
        System.out.print(arr=new int[array2[0]]);
        System.out.print(arr=new int[array2[1]]);
    }
    else if(array.length==1){
        System.out.println(arr=new int[array[0]]);
        System.out.print(arr=new int[array2[1]]);
    }
    else if(array.length==2){
        System.out.println(arr=new int[array[0]]);
        System.out.print(arr=new int[array[1]]);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("no");
        }
```

Comment: learn how to code . ar=myArr[i] is an assignment, that is not what you want there. Also: post your code here, with all relevant information: what do you expect, what do you get, ...

Comment: Post code not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace:

`System.out.print(arr=new int[array2[0]]);`

for

`System.out.print(array2[0]);`

in each line

You are declaring new arrays in each System.out call. What you see in console is the result of assignment, which i guess, is the address of your new object.

**Edit**

If you want to copy those values into a new array:

```
int arr[] = new int[2];

if(array.length==0){
    arr[0] = array2[0];
    arr[1] = array2[1];     
}
else if(array.length==1){
    arr[0] = array[0];
    arr[1] = array2[1];
}
else if(array.length==2){
    arr[0] = array[0];
    arr[1] = array[1];
}
else{
    System.out.println("no");
}

System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you sincere answer but i want to store the result into new array, any suggestions?

Comment: @anuragsharma what do you mean with the results, the addresses?

Comment: @anuragsharma then you should make the copy and the printing separately.

Comment: @anuragsharma check  my edit, i think that's what you were trying to do

Comment: Yes, 
Thank you very much

Comment: @anuragsharma you welcome, if this answer your question, please, mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Do not always create a new array.
Just create one array and loop through it using a for-loop. Then print out each element by accessing it with `ar[<index>]`.

```
int[] ar = new int[]{1,2,3,4};

for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    System.out.println(ar[i]);
}
```